# TUPEd but job has changed

Tags: contracts, united-kingdom

I was [TUPE](http://www.acas.org.uk/tupe)d in November 2014. I was told I would be offered a new contract on 1st June 2015 after training for a different part of the business.

I did the training in May and am now doing the work for the new business. But my new boss has said that I wont get offered a contract until I prove that I can do the job.

I have been doing part of the job for 15 years.

Where do I stand and what can I do?

Comment: I am on the same money, nothing changed but also dont earn bonus which is less than what I was getting

Comment: For those (like me) who had no idea what "tuped" means: http://www.acas.org.uk/tupe

Comment: What do you have in writing about the offer of a new contract?

Comment: it's hard for us to say where you stand legally; it would probably be wisest to speak to a lawyer or union rep if you have one.

Comment: @yochannah absolutely TUPE is immensely complex and has a lot of strange edge cases

Comment: @lindakerr one minor thing to note: when I TUPEd from a company that offered bonuses to a company that didn't offer bonuses, they raised my pay by the average amount of bonuses from the last few years. I don't know if that's something that a new TUPE employer is obliged to do, but it might be worth asking the question if nothing else. As we've said, speak to a lawyer or union rep - and consider pooling together with other TUPEd staff if they feel the same way. Citizens' Advice or ACAS may be able to help too.

Answer (score 2):

**You need ask your union rep, they will be able to give the most relevant advice. If you don't have one you will need to find a solicitor. We cannot provide legal advice.**

> But my new boss has said that I wont get offered a contract until I prove that I can do the job.

When you are TUPE'd, typically your old contract still stands (with some mostly minor exceptions, pensions being the biggest).

However, they may try to change the contract after the transfer and there are certain ways they can do this. This is a complex and changing area, plus the UK government has been looking for ways to make it easier for businesses to discard contract provisions of TUPE'd employees.

Moreover, if you have since been offered and accepted a job that was substantially different you may no longer be covered by TUPE.

All that said, if you work for someone, you will have a contract. It may not be written down yet, but [you have the right to see the terms of your employment contract](https://www.gov.uk/employment-contracts-and-conditions).

So you definitely need to take advice from your rep or solicitor. You should gather up every bit of communication you've had about the situation, especially your contract, terms and conditions, etc. before you were TUPE'd, and anything you received that had the word 'consultation' on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to talk to a lawyer or some one who understands TUPE, this can get very technical.

If your bonus was contractual you should still have it - was this not covered during the consolation process.